# Co-ordinate vector of the linear transformation of x

Tags: coordinate-systems, linear-transformations

$T$ is the linear transformation of $V$ ($n$-dimensional) to $W$ ($m$-dimensional) and {$b_1,...b_n$} is the basis $B$ for $V.$ Given any x in $V$, the coordinate vector $[x]_B$ is in $R^n$ and the coordinate vector of its image, $[T(x)]_C$  is in $R^m$.

$T(x)$ =T($r_1$$b_1$ + ... + $r_nb_n$)$ = T(b_1)$ + ... + r$_nT(b_n)$

How did the above equation lead to this:

$[T(x)]_C = r_1[T(b_1]_C + .... + r_n[T(b_n]_C $  ?

Looking at $[T(x)]_C$, what will be the basis, $C$ (for $W$) based on this? I know that to get $[T(x)]_C$, you will have to find some $c_1 ... c_n$ (scalar values)  that will be used to form a linear combination of $T(x)$?

Someone, please?

Comment: The $[T\left(b_1\right.]_C$ notation you are using is not standard. Can you please explain what it means?

Comment: @MattS I've updated the question

Comment: I don't see an explanation of what $[T(x)]_C$ means in the edit.

Comment: @MattS It is there now

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the function $[-]_C:W\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is an invertible linear transformation between $W$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ (an isomorphism) identifying the elements of the basis $C$ with the standard unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$. In this case the linearity condition is what is important. For any vectors $w,w'\in W$ and elements $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$[aw+bw']_C=a[w]_C+b[w']_C$$
This is because if
$$C=\{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_m\}$$
then
$$[c_1]_C=(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$$
and
$$[c_2]_C=(0,1,0,\ldots,0)$$
etc., so if $a_1,\ldots,a_m$ are real numbers, then
$$[a_1c_1+a_2c_2+\cdots +a_mc_m]_C=a_1[c_1]_C+\cdots +a_m[c_m]_C=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m)\mathrm{.}$$

If $v=a_1c_1+a_2c_2+\cdots+a_mc_m$ and $v'=a_1'c_1+a_2'c_2+\cdots+a_m'c_m$ and $p$ and $q$ are real, then
$$[pv+qv']_C=[(pa_1+qa_1')c_1+(pa_2+qa_2')c_2+\cdots+(pa_m+qa_m')c_m]_C=(pa_1+qa_1',\ldots,pa_m+qa_m')=p(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m)+q(a_1',a_2',\ldots,a_m')=p[v]_C+q[v']_C$$
This explains why
$$[T(x)]_C=r_1[T(b_1)]_C+\cdots +r_n[T(b_n)]_C$$